# Let $\lim_{x\to \infty }x^n f(x)=0$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then find the asymptote of $g$.

Tags: calculus

> Let $\lim_{x\to \infty }x^n f(x)=0$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then find the symptote
>   $$g(x)=\dfrac{x^2+f(x)}{x+1+2f(x)}.$$

---

My try :
$$\lim_{x \to \infty }\dfrac{x^2+f(x)}{x+1+2f(x)}=\lim_{x \to \infty }\dfrac{x^{n+2}+x^nf(x)}{x^{n+1}+2x^nf(x)}=\infty?$$
Please help me.

Comment: You can rewrite your $g(x)$ as $x-1+\frac{1+f(x)}{x+1
+2f(x)}$. Indeed a slant asymptote. Now apply $x^nf(x)$ part

Comment: Why $g(x)=x-1+\frac{1+f(x)}{x+1+2f(x)}$

Comment: I did long division (unless I made a mistake).

Answer (score 1):

Hint. The asymptote is oblique. Note that
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty }\frac{g(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to +\infty }\frac{x^2+f(x)}{x^2+x+2xf(x)}=1,$$
because $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}xf(x)=0$.
So it remains to find 
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty }(g(x)-x))=\lim_{x\to +\infty }\frac{x^2+f(x)-x(x+1+2f(x))}{x+1+2f(x)}\\=\lim_{x\to +\infty }\frac{f(x)-x-2xf(x)}{x+1+2f(x)}=?$$

Comment: how proof it ??

Answer (score 1):

multiply numerator by $x^n$ and denominator by $x^{n+1}$ and pass to limit you get

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{g(x)}x=1$$
Now 
$$g(x)-x=\frac{f(x)-x-2xf(x)}{x+1+2f(x)}$$
so multiplying both numerator and denominator by $x^n$ and passing to limit gives the limit $-1$ so the asymptotic is $y=x-1$.